# Test JDBC Read Side Processor in Lagom

Tags: testing, jdbc, lagom

I have a Read Side Processor that uses JdbcReadSide. In the globalPrepare method creates a table in the DB and in the handler map some entities from the event and inserts some records. How can i unit test it?